# Converting Metagraph to SavedModel in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert a .metagraph model read through tf.compat.v1.MetaGraphDef() and wrapped_import.prune as a concrete function. By using a concrete function I can take inferences from my model but I am unable to save this metagraph as a tensorflow SavedModel.

The SavedModel is then to be converted to a TF-TRT model later.

I am following the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/saved_model

The command tf.saved_model.save(model, "./model_files") gives me an error:

ValueError: Expected an object of type `Trackable`, such as `tf.Module` or a subclass of the `Trackable` class, for export. Got <ConcreteFunction pruned(input_image) at 0x7F798D69B3A0> with type <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction'>.